# Perform single SQL query over internet Android

Tags: sql, android

I am trying to find a way to goto a database located on the web perform 1 query and close the connection. I have not had any luck with finding an answer, and I really don't know how to solve this.

Internet connection is not an issue, nor is any security issues. Also this cannot be solved with an internal database and this must go across the web.

If you have any hints or ideas please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some kind of service to access the database. For example you can write something very basic in php and use HTTPClient from Android to interact with it.

[Here's](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) a brief example on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the only way to accomplish it. I will try my hand with this example. Thank you for the quick reply and the link!